# Jenkins/Hudson Upload to Testflight

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins job using xcode to build my ipa file. That is all working great. Right now I just have the Marketing version set to `${BUILD_ID}` and the technical version set to `${BUILD_NUMBER}`. I also have Release configuration specified and my job is set to archive the ipa files as a post build action. I believe those combination of settings causes my resulting IPA file to be the following:

```
Target-Configuration-BUILD_NUMBER.ipa
```

So if my target was named BillyBob and this was the 23rd successful build, my resulting .ipa file is:`BillyBob-Release-23.ipa`

I want to setup a job or post-build action to upload my file to testflight on a successful build.

I can not figure out what to set the file parameter of the testflight API to so that it will always find the latest build file, I don't think there is a wildcard available or if there is I don't know how to set it.

Originally, when I wasn't setting the technical version as part of the build I had it just pointed to the `-1.0.ipa` version of the file it was creating and that would get uploaded fine.

I've tried using both the testflight plugin for jenkins and just a curl shell script command.

I will also point out that I'm not an iOS developer, I've just been trying to help the project by setting up the automated build, so my guess as to how that file is getting generated could be way off.

***UPDATE
So it looks like this current open issue is kind of what I am looking for
[jenkins issue section](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13929?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3achangehistory-tabpanel)

For now, I just had my job specify an output path that is the workspace of my upload to testflight job.

It looks like in the Testflight app, if you don't specify anything for the IPA file, it looks for one in the workspace directory of that job. So I could probably also put in a request to the testflight plugin to allow you to specify a path in the IPA setting and have it find the .ipa file in that path, that currently does not work.

If I was better at scripting I could probably also handle it in a shell command using the curl command to upload to testflight.

Comment: I'm curious, where did you specify the ipa filename in Jenkins? I've having trouble with that right now (specifically adding the Jenkins build number to the filename)

Answer (score 1):

Leaving those fields empty in Jenkins fixed it for me.

> If you do not specify the ipa/dsym file(s) they are searched for
>   automatically in the workspace.

As you can see from:

```
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Testflight+Plugin
Version 1.3.1 (Jan 12 2012)
* Default IPA upload
```

Comment: gah! just saw your update ... oh man here come the negative votes (*cringes & assumes the fetal position*)